# Query fetching results

Tags: drupal

In drupal website we are getting sql query data exporting very slow (taking longtime) issue how to solve the issue

The query as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a.*), c.nid, b.uac_inst_campus_cricos
FROM uac_export_coursetable_latest AS a 
LEFT JOIN uac_institutiondata AS c 
    ON c.uac_institutiondata_institution = a.uac_course_institution 
LEFT JOIN uac_inst_campus_latest AS b 
    ON b.nid = c.nid AND b.uac_inst_furtherinfobox_heading = a.campusname 
WHERE a.uac_course_institution = '6628'
AND intyear12 = 'Yes' 
ORDER BY uaccoursecode
```

Answer (score 0):

Because we don't know the exact schema of your custom tables, we can't give you an exact solution but in general when query execution is slow, you need to verify the columns you are using for the `JOINS` and within the `WHERE` clausule.

- Be sure that you are joining on foreign key columns
- Be sure that indexes are set on the columns used within conditions

In your case, I would add index on following columns: `uac_institutiondata_institution` (`uac_institutiondata` table), `intyear12` (`uac_export_coursetable_latest`), `nid` (`uac_inst_campus_latest` table)

If the `uac_course_institution` column in `uac_export_coursetable_latest` table is not a primary key, also on a index on this column.

More info about indexes on a MySql database: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html